# Debug.DrawRay() does not draw rays in game view

Tags: unity, c#

Here is the relevant code:

```
protected override void Update()
{
    base.Update();

    Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward * 100f, Color.red, duration: 2f);
}
```

When running the game, I can see the ray being drawn in Scene View.

However, in Game View, no ray is displayed.

As you can see from the screenshot below, **I have already enabled gizmos in Game View.**

[image]

What should I do to ensure that rays are being drawn in Game View when debugging?

Comment: Are you sure the camera is looking at where the ray should be ? Can you see it in the editor ?

Comment: @Shashimee Yes. I can see the rays in Scene View. But I cannot see them in Game View. The camera is pointing towards the game object that implements Debug.DrawRay(...) in the Update() call.

Answer (score 7):

## `Debug.DrawRay` (and other such functions) *never* draw in the game view

They're *debug* drawings and debug info and output should never appear in the "live" program view, which is supposed to mimic the compiled executable's behavior, which strips all references to `Debug`. If you want to draw in the game window you need top use a `LineRenderer` or other runtime solution (UI objects, etc).

Comment: Turns out you can view it in the Scene view: launch game which puts it into Game view and then switch back to Scene view to see the raycast.  This was driving me crazy until I read this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without an actual screenshot showing the problem, I can only make suggestions that may or may not apply to your situation.

First, make sure that the camera is not pointed directly in the same direction as the ray being drawn. Otherwise it might only show up as infinitely in line.

Second, by default, `Debug.DrawRay` draws lines with depth testing enabled, so if the camera is behind the object, and the ray is being drawn mostly away from the camera, the object itself would obscure the line. Or there could be something else in the way. If this is the only problem, then you could simply disable depth testing:

```
Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward * 100f, Color.red, duration: 2f, depthTest: false);
```

As a sidenote, is there a reason duration is set to 2? Since this is being called in `Update`, no duration is required unless you want it to continue to be drawn after the object is disabled, or if the object is moving or rotating and you want a visual record of where it was in previous frames.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your component that draws the ray is *expanded* when viewed from the Inspector. If it's collapsed, it won't draw Debug stuff. I've waisted countless hours debugging my * caugh * debugging tools only to find out it's all down to a component being expanded or not.